# Big amount of columns in table

Tags: sql, performance

Let's assume I have table called 'orders' and inside this table I have 100 columns. I'm querying data from this table from a lot of places in my system. There are a lot of relations between this table and other tables. Now I need to add 5 more columns about which i will be querying not that often. I'm curious what is better in

1. Create additional table for that 5 columns (with 6 columns because of relation to 'order' table).
2. Add that 5 columns to table 'order'.

Comment: If a table has 100 columns, something is probably very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you have many fields in your `orders` table, and to prevent peformance issues, another approach might be to split the `orders` table into several new tables. This will prevent performance issues and probably keep things more organized. To keep relational constraints follow the steps below:

- Decide what related fields you will move to new tables and create them.
- Properly set the `foreign key` to `orders` in the new tables. I'm assumimg here that your keys are formed by a single field.
- Set the `primaty key` of the new tables to be the same field as the `foreign key`. This enforces a logical `1:1` relation: Only one secondary row can exists for evey `orders` row and no secondary rows can exists without a parent `orders` row.

What you can't achieve with this approach is that mandatory fields in secondary tables are enforced to exist at database level. You should manage this on your own or leave all mandary fields in 'orders'.